# How to Enable/Disable one field on the basis of data in other field

Tags: java

I am using eclipse and I have `two TextField` such that `one text field contains IP address` and `other contains normal text entry`.
When first text field contains IP address of local system I can insert text in the second text field while when IP is of some other system 
I have to disable the second text field.

I have added modify Listener on the first text field that checks whether to enable/disable second text field.

```
My problem is when I type IP address then on every keystroke system hangs up 
for some seconds.
```

I am using this code in my modifyText function

```
// Here ipAdd is the value of the first Text field on which i have add Modify Listener

InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(ipAdd);
byte[] ipAddr = addr.getAddress();
String ipAddrStr
        for (int i = 0; i < ipAddr.length; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                ipAddrStr += ".";
            }
            ipAddrStr += ipAddr[i] & 0xFF;
        }
        // ipAddrStr contains the IP address
// For finding name of local host

String ownSysName = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
```

Why there is a hault after every keystroke.?

Please suggest any better way to the achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to get the local machine's hostname after every keystroke.  You should get the local machine's hostname once, and stash it somewhere.

Also, you should really only be doing a comparison between the entered IP address and the local host's IP address once the user is done typing the entire IP address (when the string that has been typed matches a regex that describes an IP address as described at http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html for instance).  Comparing for every keystroke seems like a waste of energy.  You know if they've only typed one character that that's not the IP address you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it hangs because you do this in the [EDT thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), and `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();` takes relatively long to execute.

You should do all the actions that take more time in a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities:

- You may be modifying value in the text field from listener which in
  turn calls listener again and so on.
- Some method may be costly.

It will be best if you can profile the code. JVisualVM is available on most systems and can give you quick idea. Alternatively you can look at the stack trace of the busy thread and see which methods remain present even after refreshing the view when the system is hung.

Also if your goal is to disable one of the text editors, you need not do the evaluation on every key stroke. You can evaluate editability say when second text field gets focus or the focus moves out from first text field.